# How to change the encoding of a file from 'application/octet-stream' to 'text/plain' in hadoop hdfs

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming, azure-hdinsight

Im using Azure blob storage as my hadoop hdfs file directory. When I pass the input file from local machine to Azure blob storage using command prompt, the content-type is being changed to 'application/octet-stream' thereby making it unsplittable.

How to change the encoding of a hdfs file?

Comment: When you say hdfs, do you mean blobstorage? Also what program are you using to move the files?

Comment: Yes, I meant blob storage. Im looking for a unix command which does it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure-CLI to upload a blob into Azure Storage. If you have a .txt file this script will upload the file as a text/plain content type.

```
#!/bin/bash
# A simple Azure storage example

export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=<storage_account_name>
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY=<storage_account_key>

export container_name=<container_name>
export blob_name=<blob_name>

export image_to_upload=\Downloads\\uploadtest.txt

echo "Creating the container..."
azure storage container create $container_name

echo "Uploading the image..."
azure storage blob upload $image_to_upload $container_name $blob_name

echo "Listing the blobs..."
azure storage blob list $container_name

echo "Done"
```

There is not the ability to change the content type during upload. If you are using a different file type then text, you'll need to convert your file before uploading or convert your blob after upload.

Resources:

[Azure Docs - CLI Install](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-install/)

[Azure Docs - How to upload](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-azure-cli/)